# LaTeXiT and lualatex: auto-crop TikZ picture fails

Tags: luatex, crop, latexit

I'm using the very convenient LaTeXiT tool to incorporate equations and TikZ pictures within a Keynote presentation.  Mostly this works smoothly, using the `pdflatex` engine for typesetting.

However, I would like to be able to take advantage of TikZ's `graphdrawing` library, which requires the `lualatex` engine.  I can set the typesetting engine in LaTeXiT's preferences menu, but the auto-crop feature of LaTeXiT doesn't seem to work with `lualatex`.  The image that results is as large as an entire page or so.

Is there any way I can recover auto-crop for `lualatex`, or is there any package that I can add to crop the result automatically?

For a minimal *not*-working example, the LaTeXiT preamble could be

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %used for font color
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
```

and the body could be as simple as

```
A
```

Comment: Did you make a bug report?

Comment: No, I was hoping it was my error and not a bug.  :-)  I can certainly create a bug report.